# Finding conditions filters based on data

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I have a data structured into table and I'm wondering if there is any way I could find connection based on this data so I got some kind of conditions/filters based on which data is presented?

Which tools could be useful ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just manually checking to find my own conclusions. I'm looking for some tips where to start. I am at the beginning of learning python and I wonder where to start when it comes to the presented problem.